# maven site unpack error

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a multi module maven project. If I run

```
mvn clean install
```

everything works fine. But if I run:

```
mvn site
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:unpack (copy-war) @ module2 ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: com.example:module1:1.0-SNAPSHOT:war
Unpacking path\2\module1\target\classes to path\2\module2\target\module1 with includes "" and excludes ""
org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: The source must not be a directory.
```

With `mvn clean install` at the same point I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:unpack (copy-war) @ module2 ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: com.example:module1:1.0-SNAPSHOT:war
[INFO] Unpacking path\2\module1\target\module1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to path\2\module2\target\module1 with includes "" and excludes ""
```

and everything works fine.

Any idea why the dependency plugin wants to unpack a directory instead of a war?

Comment: Not sure why this was -1'ed, seems like a reasonable question

Comment: During which phase is 'maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:unpack' being run?

Comment: The plugin is defined in the build phase.

Comment: It would be great if someone gives a reason when someone -1 a question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. I disabled the site plugin for that module:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <generateReports>false</generateReports>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I think the comand fails due to a bug in the site plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a long standing (since 2007!) bug in maven-dependency-plugin. Have a look at the [MDEP-98 JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-98) for a discussion and possible workarounds.